# Is there an actual risk of memory leak when applying migratons in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, garbage-collection, entity-framework-migrations

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#apply-migrations-at-runtime), one may utilize the fact that migrations implmenet `IDisposable` like this.

```
using IServiceScope scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Context>()
  .Database.Migrate();
```

However, I usually call the migration as follows and have never experienced any issues.

```
app.Services.CreateScope()
  .ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Context>()
    .Database.Migrate();
```

Is there a good reason in practice to worry? I figure, the migration is carried out once only, at the start and in most cases doesn't even carry out any changes, hence occupying the requested instance of the scope minimal amount of time. It's not asynchronous, neither, which to me additionally lowers the likelihood of it running amok.

Please note that I'm **not** advocating to omit `using` in that case. I understand the importance of following best-practices. But I'm also curious how important it is pragmatically.

Comment: Which version of EF? EF Core 6 is currently latest (and has a different tag than you're using).

Comment: @gunr2171 I'm using the latest version. Does it affect the practical consideration of my question? Also, which tag are you referring to?

Comment: I'd be surprised, mildly stated, if migrations would cause memory leaks. I see no reason for it to use unmanaged code and we may assume it closes (& disposes) any connection it opens.

Comment: @GertArnold Could you post it as an answer, preferably with some reference, please? The reason is that, while I agree with you, I have colleagues who disagree. I suspect that it may be unsupported belief on their side (simply because they noticed the disposable interface) but I'd like to have some more muscles behind my stance. How could such a thing be confirmed/disproved?

Comment: The problem is, I don't have any reference. It's just that I trust the EF team and my gut feeling (in that order).

Comment: @GertArnold No worry. I share your trust priority order, too.